# It is semantically correct to use <header> inside <section>?

Tags: html, semantics

All examples I found on Internet refers to using `<h1>` inside `<section>`, but nothing related to the use of `<header>` element.

It's valid HTML5, but what about semantics?

Maybe I'm misusing the `<section>` element, for the completeness here is my use case:

```html
<main role="main">
  <header>page header</header>
  <section id="cookiesPolicy">
    <header>
      <h1>Cookies Policiy</h1>
    </header>
    <div>Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</div>   
  </section>    
  <footer>page footer</footer>
</main>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes it is semantically correct to use `header` inside `section`

> **header –** There is a crucial difference between the `header` element and
> the general accepted usage of `header` (or masthead). There’s usually
> only one `header` or ‘masthead’ in a page. In HTML5 you can have as many
> as you want. The spec defines it as “a group of introductory or
> navigational aids”. You can use a `header` in any `section` on your site.
> In fact, you probably should use a `header` within most of your
> sections. The spec describes the `section` element as “a thematic
> grouping of content, typically with a heading.”

[Source](https://clzd.me/html5-section-aside-header-nav-footer-elements-not-as-obvious-as-they-sound/)

You can also check `header` W3 specs [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element)

Comment: After years and years of HTML5 I still learn new things all the time, like `header` and `hgroup`. Thanks for this info!

Comment: "typcially with a heading" does not necessarily mean `<header>` is may just mean `<h1>`...

Answer (score 1):

`header` is:

> introductory content for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element.

`section` is a valid sectioning content, so `header` is semantically correct - even encouraged - in this position.

Quote taken from [this HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/) page, which actually quotes [the HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element) directly.