# Header- Footer Tag inside Section Tag?

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML5 markup.

I'm wondering if I'm allowed to have a header and footer tag within section tag like the below:

```
<section>
  <header>
    <h2>HEADER</h2>
  </header>
  <p>Section's Content</p>
  <footer>
    <h2>FOOTER</h2>
  </footer>
</section>
```

Or is it better to replace them with div tag and set classes for them.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The HTML specification is very clear about this.

Comment: yes you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37121520/it-is-semantically-correct-to-use-header-inside-section) answer

Answer (score 4):

According to MDN you can use it.

[Header tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header)
**Permitted parents**:  `Any element that accepts flow content`. Note that a  element must not be a descendant of an `<address>, <footer>` or another `<header>` element.

[Footer tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer)
**Permitted parents**:  `Any element that accepts flow content`. Note that a  element must not be a descendant of an `<address>, <header>` or another `<footer>` element.

And `section` is a [flow content element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section). You can have header and footer tags in it.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to do something like that (you can also replace `section` by `div`, if you want)

```
  <header>
    <h2>HEADER</h2>
  </header>
  <section>
    <p>Section's Content</p>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <h2>FOOTER</h2>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Dear Zahori,

thank you for your respond. I have already Header tag and Footer tag for the whole content. But I have 5 sections within the main tag and every section tag has h2 and div tag with the class "section-footer". That's why I'm wondering if is it better to set header and footer tags for every section.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many header tags as you want, and place them in almost any other element with some exceptions:

**Header**
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp

> Note: A `<header>` tag cannot be placed within a `<footer>`,
>   `<address>` or another `<header>` element.

**Footer**
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp

> The `<footer>` tag defines a footer for a document or section.

So `<header>` and `<footer>` are fine within sections, the corresponding w3c links even explicitly states that they are fine to use within sections.